# Error when trying to run serverless offline on plugin serverless-reqvalidator-plugin

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm using serverless to deploy lambda functions. When I execute `serverless offline start` I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: serverless.configSchemaHandler.defineFunctionEventProperties is not a function
  at new ServerlessReqValidatorPlugin (C:\asd\asd\asd\SaveBidItem\node_modules\serverless-reqvalidator-plugin\src\index.js:50:36)
  at PluginManager.addPlugin (C:\Users\Univ Ovidius\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:94:28)
```

Comment: Provide your plugin list in your serverless.yml file

Comment: This the the plugin list

"plugins": [
    "serverless-offline",
    "serverless-reqvalidator-plugin",
    "serverless-aws-documentation",
    "serverless-webpack"
  ]